# How do I configure Serilog to print special characters correctly?

Tags: asp.net-core, special-characters, serilog

I use Serilog as a rolling file logger.
At the start of a console application I call this custom extension method on ILogger.

```
        public static void LogStartExecution<TCategoryName>(this ILogger<TCategoryName> logger)
        {
            logger.LogInformation("DÉBUT Traitement {0}", typeof(TCategoryName));
        }

        public static void ConfigureLogging(IServiceCollection services, LoggingConfig loggingConfig)
        {
            // Initialize serilog logger
            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                 .WriteTo.File(path: @$"{loggingConfig.Path}\{loggingConfig.FileName}",
                               rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day,
                               rollOnFileSizeLimit: true,
                               fileSizeLimitBytes: 5000000,
                               retainedFileCountLimit: 100)
                 .MinimumLevel.Debug()
                 .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                 .CreateLogger();

            // Add logging
            services.AddLogging(loggingBuilder =>
            {
                loggingBuilder.AddConsole();
                loggingBuilder.AddSerilog();
                loggingBuilder.AddDebug();
            });
        }
```

The resulting output is like so :
2020-05-19 19:39:56.158 -04:00 [INF] DÃ‰BUT Traitement Xnt.Annotation.Retrait.TraitementRetrait

The special character 'É' appears like gibberish.

How can I configure Serilog to output special characters correctly. 
Culture should be fr-CA

Comment: How are you configuring your sinks?

Comment: @C.AugustoProiete added the configuration

Comment: How are you viewing the resulting log file? If in a termina/console, is likely a codepage issue. If not - is your C# source file UTF-8? - HTH

Comment: @NicholasBlumhardt the output is a plain .txt. When opened in Notepad++ the special characters are rendered correctly, not if opened in Windows-Notepad. I added the parameter encoding: Encoding.UTF8 to .WriteTo.File and this solves the issue. Good tip thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding the parameter 'encoding: Encoding.UTF8' solves the issue.

```
.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
   .WriteTo.File(path: @$"{loggingConfig.Path}\{loggingConfig.FileName}",
                 rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day,
                 rollOnFileSizeLimit: true,
                 fileSizeLimitBytes: 5000000,
                 retainedFileCountLimit: 100,
                 encoding: Encoding.UTF8)
```